# How can i fix local asset error in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Can someone tell me why the picture cannot be displayed?

### #

When I take a picture from the Internet with "NetworkImage" it works. Is there a local solution too?

#### #

I tried a lot around but even the posts here in the forum can not help me.

```
  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:

  assets:
    - images/mio.jpg
```

-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Main());
}

class Main extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 250,
          height: 250,
          color: Colors.grey,
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: 200,
                height: 300,
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: 0,
                right: 0,
                child: Container(
                  width: 200,
                  height: 300,
                  child: Image(
                    fit: BoxFit.contain,
                    image: AssetImage(
                      'images/mio.jpg',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[I get this error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2EDB.png)

[image: #### PUB ####]

Comment: Did you restart the app after adding the images? Not hot restart.

Comment: Yes, I tried everything. I think it's the code.

Comment: can you show your pubspec.yaml?

Comment: sure, i added it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are getting this error but you should try

```
Asset.Image(
  'images/mio.jpg',
  fit: BoxFit.contain,
),
```

instead of

```
Image(
  fit: BoxFit.contain,
  image: AssetImage(
     'images/mio.jpg',
   ),
),
```

another suggestion would be to not declare all your images in your pubspec.yaml, because there is a chance of human mistype error, you should just declare the root folder of your images, in your case

```
  assets:
    - images/
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's three solution

**First** make sure that there's only one tap before assets and two taps before the image path

**Second** change these lines of code

```
  Image(
    fit: BoxFit.contain,
    image: AssetImage(
      'images/mio.jpg',
    ),
```

and write this instead that works for me

```
Image.asset(
          'images/mio.jpg',
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
```

**Third** use flutter clean than flutter run